# Prove that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=0$ if $f(\frac{1}{n})=1$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ and $f(x)=0$ for all other $x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

> Prove that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=0$ if $f(\frac{1}{n})=1$ for
>   $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ and $f(x)=0$ for all other $x$.

---

**Lemma:** If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $f(x)=\mathbb{1}_{\{c\}}$ for some $a<c<b$, then $\int_a^b f(x)dx=0$.

*Proof of the lemma:*

Consider a partition of $[a,b]$ such that its width is less than $\delta>0$. Then the absolute value of Riemann sum corresponding to this partition is less than $2 \delta $. So for any $\epsilon>0$ we can choose $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and we will have $|S|<\epsilon$ whenever $S$ is a Riemann sum corresponding to a partition of width less than $\delta$.

*Proof of the main result:*

Choose $\epsilon>0$. From the above lemma and linearity of the Riemann integral, we know that $$\int_{\epsilon/2}^1f(x)dx=0 \mbox{.}$$

Thus there is a step function $g:[\frac{\epsilon}{2},1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $0\le f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\in[\frac{\epsilon}{2},1]$ and $$ \int_{\epsilon/2}^1 g(x)dx <\epsilon /2 \mbox{.}$$

Define a new step function $h:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x)=g(x)$ if $x\in  [\frac{\epsilon}{2},1]$ and $h(x)=1$ if $x\in [0,\frac{\epsilon}{2})$. It is clear that for all $x\in [0,1]$ we have

$$0\le f(x) \le h(x) \mbox{.}$$

Also $$ \int_{0}^1 h(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\epsilon/2} dx  + \int_{\epsilon/2}^1 g(x)dx <\epsilon /2+ \epsilon /2 =\epsilon \mbox{.}$$

Thus we proved that $f$ is integrable. It remains to show that the integral $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ is equal to $0$. We know that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ exists and however small $\alpha$ we choose, the integral $\int_{\alpha}^1 f(x)dx$ also exists and is equal to $0$. The result follows from continuity of the integral.

I would be very grateful if somebody verified my proof, I'm quite not sure about the very last part. Thank you.

Comment: Note that your result is a particular statement of the much more general (and useful) [Lebesgue integrability criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability) for the Riemann integral.

Comment: @AlexM. I know that criterion, but I wanted to prove it without using it ;) It's fun.

Comment: On the one hand the function $f(x)=1$, if $x$ irrational and $f(x)=0$, if $x$ rational is not Riemann - integrable, on the other hand the Lebesgue criterion says that is should be Riemann - integrable because the set of discontinuities has measure zero. What am I missing?

Comment: @Stef You are mistaken. The set of discontiunities of that function is whole $\mathbb{R}$ (it is discontinuous everywhere). Rationals are dense in reals.

Comment: Ok, this explains it. Thanks

Comment: What is the relation between $f$ and $g$ in your lemma and its proof?

Comment: @uniquesolution it was a typo, corrected

Comment: Would it not be simple enough to say your function is non-zero on a set of measure zero, thus the value of the integral follows...

Comment: Funny. If your proof is correct, how should an answer look in order to get the bounty? Would "I've checked your proof and it is correct" suffice?

Comment: @AlexM. Yes, all I need is verification. I am at the stage where I don't trust myself in mathematics too much.

Comment: I don't get the existence of $g$. By "step function" do you understand a function that is $0$ up to a point, and $1$ afterwards (from left to right)? If so, then choose $\varepsilon = 1$. Since $f \le g$ on $[\frac 1 2, 1]$ and $f(\frac 1 2) = f(1) = 1$, I deduce that $g = 1$, so its integral on $[\frac 1 2, 1]$ is $\frac 1 2$, which clearly is not *strictly* less than $\frac 1 2$ as you claim. You also say that "Thus, there is a step function", but I don't understand the "thus", since I don't see how $g$ is obtained from the considerations preceding its introduction.

Comment: @AlexM Step function is a functon that assumes only a finite number of distinct values. I used one of the equivalent definitions of Riemann integrability. If for every $\epsilon>0$ there are step functions $f_1, f_2$ such that for all $x$ we have $f_1(x)\le f(x) \le f_2(x)$ and $\int_a^b (f_2(x)-f_1(x))dx < \epsilon$ then $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof looks OK to me, perhaps a little long. At the end, you certainly can use continuity if you like, but I don't think you need to. You have $f$ Riemann integrable and $0\le f\le h.$ Thus $0\le\int_0^1f \le \int_0^1 h < \epsilon.$ Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small, $\int_0^1f=0.$

The upper/lower sums approach to the Riemann integral might be a simpler route to the result. For $n\in \mathbb N,$ let $P_n$ be the uniform partion of $[0,1]$ into subintervals of length $1/n^2.$ We then have

$$0 = L(P_n,f)\le U(P_n,f) = \sum_{k=1}^{n^2}M_k\cdot \frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}M_k\cdot \frac{1}{n^2} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{n^2}M_k\cdot \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

The first sum on the right is $\le n\cdot 1 \cdot (1/n^2).$ For the second sum, think about the points $1,1/2,\dots ,1/n.$ Each of these points can lie in at most two subintervals determined by $P_n.$ Thus the second sum is at most $2\cdot n\cdot 1 \cdot (1/n^2).$ Adding these up gives

$$0 = L(P_n,f)\le U(P_n,f) \le \frac{n+2n}{n^2} =\frac{3}{n}.$$

Letting $n\to \infty$ shows the difference between upper and lower sums can be made arbitrarily small, which implies $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1].$ Because $U(P_n,f) \to 0$ and $\int_0^1f \le U(P_n,f) $ for any $n,$ we have $\int_0^1f = 0$ as desired.